# osiset / laravel-shopify - Authenticate user in Webhook

Tags: php, laravel, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am new to shopify app development. I want to make ADMIN API call in Laravel Jobs that is when webhook notification is triggered.

Here is the details of app flow:

1. Customer creates order in merchant shop
2. Order-create webhook is triggered
3. When order-create webhook notification is received I want to call billing api with type usage charge.

The main problem I have is how to authenticate user in webhook. I know to authenticate the user within Shopify admin using $shop = Auth::user(); $shopApi = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/shop.json')['body']['shop'];. But this donot work in Laravel Job handle method.

I was thinking to save the access-token that is generated " $shop = Auth::user(); $shopApi = $shop->api()". But I can't seem to find the way to access the access_token and save it into the database so that I can use same access_token to make billing api requests.
[image]
Is this approach the best approach. Does access_token has any expiry date?

Please recommend if there is any best approach as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to access user from job class. So in this package in every job class, you can easily found the shopDomain `$this->shopDomain`. So then just get the data of the user from that respective shopDomain:

```
$shop = User::where('name', $this->shopDomain)->first();
```

If there is a shop then:

```
$shopApi = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/shop.json')['body']['shop'];
```

I hope this will help you. If there is any issue, please comment here.